# Aplicar class com innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

Estou usando innerHTML para alterar um valor de uma `<td>` que possui uma classe. Consigo aplicar a class junto? Pois o retorno vem sem classe.

### HTML:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" class="tabelaPadrao">
    <tr class="totais">
        <td align="left" width="52%" id="totalOp"><b>Total de operações</b></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### JS:

```
function tipoOperacao(tipo){ 
    if (tipo.value == 'todas'){
        document.getElementById('totalOp').innerHTML="Total de operações";
    } else if (tipo.value == 'cielo'){
        document.getElementById('totalOp').innerHTML="Total de operações Cielo";
    }
}
```

Comment: Aos _downvoters_: em prol da comunidade, faz-se bem comentar maneiras de como melhorar a questão.

Comment: Claudia, você poderia esclarecer o que você quer dizer com classe? Você quer alterar a `td` e incluir uma classe `CSS`? Ou você está querendo manter o `<b>`?

Comment: Por que não utiliza `innerText` para trocar texto, se `innerHTML` pode substituir todos conteudos.

Comment: Anthony, eu queria manter somente o negrito, fui testando e resolvi meu problema colocando o "id"  no "<b>". Obrigada!!   : )

Comment: Só uma dica: Para atribuir um valor de dados para um elemento, ao invés de usar o método inseguro, como element.innerHTML = data, prefira uma opção mais segura como: element.textContent = data. Assim você não fica vulnerável a ataques de Cross-site scripting (XSS).

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o className. Se for para adicionar a classe no elemento totalOp, faça o seguinte:

```
function tipoOperacao(tipo){ 
    if (tipo.value == 'todas'){
        document.getElementById('totalOp').className = "classeA";
        document.getElementById('totalOp').innerHTML="Total de operações";
    } else if (tipo.value == 'cielo'){
        document.getElementById('totalOp').className = "classeB";
        document.getElementById('totalOp').innerHTML="Total de operações Cielo";
    }
}
```

Comment: Lembrando: re-atribuindo a propriedade `className` dessa forma pode remover classes existentes.

Answer (score 0):

Para adicionar e remover uma classe específica do elemento `'#totalOp'` você pode utilizar a interface [`ClassList()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) que pode ser achada na propriedade `classList` do seu elemento.

Uma `ClassList()` tem mais do que 2 métodos, mas esses são os fundamentais:

- `ClassList().add`: adiciona uma classe ao elemento;
- `ClassList().remove`: remove uma classe do elemento.

```html
function tipoOperacao(tipo){ 
    if (tipo.value == 'todas'){
        document.getElementById('totalOp')).classList.add("classe");
        document.getElementById('totalOp').innerHTML="Total de operações";
    } else if (tipo.value == 'cielo'){
        document.getElementById('totalOp').classList.remove("classe");
        document.getElementById('totalOp').innerHTML="Total de operações Cielo";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

É impossível aplicar uma classe para seu elemento `'td'` re-atribuindo `innerHTML`, sendo que ele é só o interior HTML de sí. `outerHTML` que seria o correto, portanto seria trabalhoso e problemático aos elementos interiores.

É mais fácil usar métodos do navegador que permitem manipular as classes de um elemento facilmente.

Até agora, de acordo com as respostas nessas perguntas, temos duas formas de manipular as classes de um elemento:

- Re-atribuindo a propriedade `className` (que é um setter).
- Pegando a interface `ClassList` na propriedade `classList`, chamando seus métodos `add`, `remove`, etc.

Na minha opinião não faz muita diferença re-atribuir `className` em um elemento que pode conter até o máximo *uma* classe, mas seria melhor usar os métodos de `ClassList()` quando for modificar um elemento contendo várias classes, assim você não vai perder elas.

Não é bom re-atribuir `className` quando um elemento pode ter classes dinâmicas, mas ainda é possível manter classes com ele, porém de uma forma mais diferente.

Então, re-atribuindo `className`:

```js
/* perdeu a classe 'ball' */
wow.className = "new-class";

/* agora só resta 1 bola, portanto 'wow' não foi removido */
```

```css
.ball {
  background-color: #f05;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ball"></div>
<div class="ball" id="wow"></div>
```

Usando `ClassList()`:

```js
wow.classList.add("new-class");

/* ainda restam 2 bolas */
```

```css
.ball {
  background-color: #f05;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ball"></div>
<div class="ball" id="wow"></div>
```